# [JEST]How can I define optional parameter when use .toMatchObject?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to use .toMatchObject to check the structure of an web response data.

In my plan, I can use .toMatchObject() like Typescript, what I need do is just define an object and call 
`expect(res.result).toMatchObject(matchObj);`

For those optional parameter, I use expect.extend to define a funciton to check parameter is undefined or some class I wanted.

But by my test, when some parameter isn't defined, jest will just throw an error with not call function in expect.extend.

How can I achieve this feature?

There is my code. `expect.toBeUnnessary` is defined in expect.extend. It check the parameter is undefined or some class.

```
const categoryObj = {
  CategoryID: expect.any(Number),
  Index: expect.any(Number),
  Name: expect.any(String),
  Children: expect.toBeUnnessary(Array)
};
expect(category).toMatchObject(categoryObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect.objectContaining:

```js
expect({ a: 1, b: 2, optional: 3 }).toMatchObject(
    expect.objectContaining({ a: 1, b: 2 }),
);
```